# React communicate with others components

Tags: reactjs

i have these components "Portlet", "PortletTitle","PortletTool","PortletBody" . All work fine, but now i want add a simple interaction between components.

to use in my app:

```
<Portlet>
  <PortletTitle>
    <PortletTool toolCollapse={true}>
  </PortletTitle>
  <PortletBody>bla vla bla </PortletBody>
</Portlet>
```

PortletTool.js

```
class PortletTools extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = { toolCollapse: PropTypes.bool };
    state = { collaped: false };

    handler = () => {
        let newstate = !this.state.collaped;
        this.setState({ collaped: newstate });
    };

    render() {
        const classCollaped = !this.state.collaped ? "collapse" : "expand";
        let toolCollapse = this.props.toolCollapse
            ? <a href="javascript:;" className={classCollaped} title="" data-original-title="" onClick={this.handler}>{" "}</a>
            : "";

        return (
            <div className="tools">
                {toolCollapse}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

PortletBody have a props "showbody" to hide/show the element, but i can now with this structure (already used in other page of application) click on my PortletTool e hide/show my PortletBody? Yes, how to?

I must (if possible) do this in "Portet" component.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add some interaction between any children components, then you're in a position where it would be helpful to [lift state up.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) In this case, you'd want to move the collapsed state up in to your `Portlet` component, register a handler that changes the state in your `Portlet` class, bind the context, and pass that handler down to your `PortletTool.` You would also want to pass the `collapsed` state in to your `PortletBody` via `props`.

For example:

```
class Portlet extends React.Component {
  state={collaped:false};
    handler=()=>{
    let newstate=!this.state.collaped;
    this.setState({collaped:newstate});
    }

   render() {
    return (
      <PortletTitle>
          <PortletTool handler={this.handler}>
        </PortletTitle>
        <PortletBody collapsed={this.state.collapsed}>bla vla bla </PortletBody>
      )
   }
}
```

Then assign the handler to an onClick prop somewhere in your `PortletTool`.  If you get a `cannot read property of undefined` error then you need to [bind the context to the handler](http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html).

Comment: correct i know, but in many page i must change the code. it's not possibile create this interaction now, with the actual situation?remember, in each page the people have create the structure with portlet->title->tool, body not have used a single component portlet.